# Resizing root partition in azure CentOS VM

Tags: centos, partition, fdisk

I have a 128 GB SSD Managed disk in Linux - CentOS 7.3. The root partition now shows 30 GB approx and is mounted under "/", ie root. lsblk shows the remaining - So we are good for now.

My requirement is that I need 20 GB under "/" and the remaining 108 GB approx in /opt. Please be careful - the machine is running on Azure.

The root partition is partitioned as XFS. It's a physical partition - meaning no LVM. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Broken crystal ball here, you are out of luck today.

Answer (score 2):

@Lambo-Fan 128 GB SSD is your Data disk, you cannot merge data disk to OS disk. you need to expand OS disk seperatly, Microsoft Azure have a functionality to increase OS disk. Please follow the below steps to increase OS disk for CentOS/RHEL/Ubuntu

Follow the following steps from the Azure Portal:

1. Login portal.azure.com open the VM and Go to the VM Overview pane and stop the VM
2. Once the VM is Stopped (deallocated) state, go to the Disks pane
3. Click on the OS disk link
4. Enter the new size in the Size text box and click on Save
5. Once the operation is completed, go back to the VM Overview pane and click on Start

For Red Hat 7.x / CentOS 7.x :

1) Login to the VM using SSH, we can check the size of the disk by using:

## lsblk

2) To proceed with the partition resize, we will use:

## sudo fdisk /dev/sda

type: **p**

this will show both partitions /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2 which are basically partitions 1 and 2

type: **d** then 2 (to delete partition 2)

type: **n** then p, 2 (to recreate partition 2) you can accept the default values

type: **w** (to save the new partition)

type: **q** (to exit fdisk)

sudo reboot (to reboot the VM so the partition is updated)

3) To finalize the resize, after the reboot, execute the command:

For Red Hat 7.3 and CentOS 7.3:

## sudo xfs_growfs /dev/sda2

4) Use the command: df -h to verify its size:
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       100G  1.6G   98G   2% /

Below document will help more inforation to increase the OS Disk
**How to: Resize Linux osDisk partition on Azure**

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/linuxonazure/2017/04/03/how-to-resize-linux-osdisk-partition-on-azure/

Comment: I found that the / partition cannot be shrinked, I simply the steps that you mentioned and it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Azure thus I cannot explain the details.

The usual approach would be

1. to boot the system from a different device
2. resize the root filesystem (which you haven't even mentioned)
3. resize the root partition (after making a backup of the partition table to a safe place)
4. create an additional partition
5. Run `mkfs` for the desired filesystem on that partition
6. mount the FS to a temporary mount point (e.g. `/mnt/tmp`)
7. move the contents of `/opt` into the new FS
8. make an entry in `/etc/fstab` for the new volume and `/opt`

Comment: Hi @Hauke,

Thanks for helping out. The file system is xfs. This is what lsblk shows.

NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0      2:0    1    4K  0 disk
sda      8:0    0  128G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2   8:2    0 29.5G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0   16G  0 disk
└─sdb1   8:17   0   16G  0 part /mnt/resource

I would like to have 20 GB under / and remaining 108 GB under /opt

Comment: Edit these into your question. Don't post important information in the comment.

Comment: @WeijunZhou And you do not forget to address the one you are talking to explicitly if you are not commenting under his question or answer because otherwise he does not get notified.